# Is it good to give a new_session_name for each new session? how this works?

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies

Is it good to give a new_session_name for each new session?
Will COOKIE, who keeps session id, keep it in the variable  new_session_name, and automatically retrieve the right data for the session?

Does this affect all users, or only the one user?
I would like to save session to database, is session name related to database name?

```
 $status =session_status();
    if( $status== 'PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE' ) {
        if( !empty($_SESSION['sessName']) ) { $this->sessName = $_SESSION['sessName']; }
    } else {
        $this->sessName = $this->genRandomStr(8);
        $previous_name = session_name($this->sessName);
        //ini_set('session.name', 'session_id');
        //ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $lifetime);
    }
```

Comment: *"Is it good to give a new_session_name for each new session?"* - Short answer: yes. *"Does this affect all users, or only the one user?"* - It should affect "only" the one user. If this were the same session id for everyone, there'd be a serious problem, where everyone could see everyone else's data.

Comment: session_id, is not the same as session.name. Session id can be regenerated. But i can not find may data about the session.name.